# Which package contains a word database or dictionary with part of speech information?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation, software-recommendation

The homepage for the [`scowl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/scowl) package says at http://wordlist.aspell.net/

> SCOWL (...) is a database of information on English words (...) The database primary contains information on (...) (basic) part-of-speech and (...)

And at http://wordlist.aspell.net/agid-readme/

> ```
> A typical entry will look like
> WORD V: WORDed, WORed 2, WORD {EXPL} | WORDing, WORing 2 | WORDs
> <pos> is V for verb, N for noun, or A or adjective or adverb.
> ```

This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, the mentioned file `infl.txt` doesn't seem to be part of the package? And doesn't seem to be part of any other package?

Which package does contain this file and/or is there any other package which contains a file with similar contents? (Doesn't matter which package, `scowl` is only the first one, I found.)

Comment: The search in [their source code](https://github.com/en-wl/wordlist/search?p=1&q=infl.txt&unscoped_q=infl.txt) gives name of the interesting script [`make-infl`](https://github.com/en-wl/wordlist/blob/d97b6785bdca75ddacfcbf73aeb9aaf42bc7accf/agid/make-infl). You have to try using it.

Comment: no I do not. Moreover there are no such files in [ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=make-infl). The script may be found [on github](https://github.com/en-wl/wordlist/blob/d97b6785bdca75ddacfcbf73aeb9aaf42bc7accf/agid/make-infl).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found one:

[`wordnet`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wordnet) which installs four files `/usr/share/wordnet/index.adj`, `/usr/share/wordnet/index.adv`, `/usr/share/wordnet/index.noun` and `/usr/share/wordnet/index.verb` for adjectives, adverbs, nouns and verbs, respectively.

The documentation at https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wndb5wn explains the file format:

> Index File Format
>
> Each index file begins with several lines containing a copyright notice, version number, and license agreement. These lines all begin with two spaces and the line number so they do not interfere with the binary search algorithm that is used to look up entries in the index files. All other lines are in the following format. In the field descriptions, number always refers to a decimal integer unless otherwise defined.
>
> lemma  pos  synset_cnt  p_cnt  [ptr_symbol...]  sense_cnt  tagsense_cnt   synset_offset  [synset_offset...]
>
> (...)